# Extremely slow compilation of webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

Our application is based on Angular 4.0. We're trying very hard to reduce the compilation time using webpack 3.8.1.

Currently it takes around 23 to 25 minutes to compile for every change.

Our application has 514 modules and 313 chunks. Some of the modules are lazy loaded. We are using system.import from webpack to dynamically import these modules.

We want to reduce the time taken by advanced module optimization.

We tried almost all the solutions that are related to this issue but no luck.

Below are the build stats:

```
59944ms [0] building modules
137455ms [0] sealing
2ms [0] optimizing
1ms [0] basic module optimization
91ms [0] module optimization
1379558ms [0] advanced module optimization
1ms [0] basic chunk optimization
0ms [0] chunk optimization
1ms [0] advanced chunk optimization
1ms [0] module and chunk tree optimization
1ms [0] chunk modules optimization
0ms [0] advanced chunk modules optimization
56ms [0] module reviving
14ms [0] module order optimization
33ms [0] module id optimization
35ms [0] chunk reviving
63ms [0] chunk order optimization
150ms [0] chunk id optimization
385ms [0] hashing
4ms [0] module assets processing
1356ms [0] chunk assets processing
24ms [0] additional chunk assets processing
1ms [0] recording
2ms [0] additional asset processing
2ms [0] chunk asset optimization
11288ms [0] asset optimization
630ms [0] emitting
[0] Hash: e37b2ca0d0e832e77295
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Child
    Hash: e37b2ca0d0e832e77295
    Time: 1591168ms
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "shipcom",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build:libs": "webpack --config stdpkgs.webpack.config.js",
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Shipcom"
  ],
  "author": "MS",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.38.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.21.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^1.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-charts": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^1.0.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "class-transformer": "0.1.6",
    "codemirror": "^5.26.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "keycode-js": "0.0.4",
    "less": "^2.3.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng-dynamic": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.5.2",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.0.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.8.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
    "@types/node": "6.0.46",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.8",
    "happypack": "^4.0.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.11.2",
    "parallel-webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.4.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.50.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here is tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ] 
  },
  "files": [
    "app/main.ts",
    "app/index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"        
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "skipDeclarationFilesCheck ": true,    
    "transpileOnly": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Below is my webpack.config file:

```
> /// <binding AfterBuild='Run - Development' Clean='Run - Development'
> /> var webPack = require('webpack'); var htmlWebPack =
> require('html-webpack-plugin'); var path = require('path'); var
> BundleAnalyzerPlugin =
> require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
> 
> var config = {
>     //Updated entrypoints to use files with ngfactory bootstrap implementation for AOT
>     entry: {
>         'app': './app/main-aot.ts',
>         'appl': './app/appMain-aot.ts',
>         'polyfills':'./deps/polyfills.ts'
>     },
> 
>     resolve: {
>         extensions: ['.ts', '.js', 'css'],
>         symlinks: false,
>         cacheWithContext: false,
>         modules: [
>             path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
>             path.resolve(__dirname, 'source')]
>     },
> 
>     devtool: 'eval',
> 
>     module: {
>         rules: [
>             {
>                 test: /\.ts$/,
>                 exclude: '/node_modules/',
>                 //Updated rules to use angular-router-loader with aot path configuration 
>                 use: [
>                 'awesome-typescript-loader',
>                 'angular-router-loader?aot=true&genDir=aot/',
>                 'angular2-template-loader'
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 test: /\.html$/,
>                 loader: 'raw-loader'
>             },
>             {
>                 test: /\.css$/,
>                 use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
>             },
>             {
>                 test: /\.scss$/,
>                 use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
>             },
>             {
>                 test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
>                 loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
>             },
>             {
>                 test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//,
>                 loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'
>             },
>             {
>                 test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
>                 use: [
>                         { loader: "file-loader", options: { hash: "sha512", digest: "hex", name: "[hash].[ext]" } },
>                         { loader: "image-webpack-loader", options: { bypassonDebug: true, optimizationLevel: 7, interlaced: false } }
>                 ]
>             }
>         ]
>     },
> 
>     plugins: [
>         new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
> 
>         new webPack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
>             /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
>             path.resolve(__dirname, './')
>         ),
> 
>         new webPack.ProvidePlugin({
>             jQuery: 'jquery',
>             $: 'jquery',
>             jquery: 'jquery'
>         }),
> 
>         new webPack.DllReferencePlugin({
>             context: path.resolve(__dirname),
>             manifest: require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/stdpkgs-manifest.json'))
>         }),
>           ],
>     output: {
>         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
>         filename: '[name].js',
>         //library: '[name]_lib',
>         chunkFilename: 'chunk/[name].js',
>         publicPath: 'dist/',
>     } }; module.exports = config;
```

Comment: You mean on the development environment right ?

Comment: Yes, this is on the development environment @Nour

Comment: First you can add: "devtool":"eval", and set the chunk count to infinity.

Comment: I am already using "devtool":"eval" @Nour. How would setting chunk count to infinity will improve build time, can you please explain? I added package.json,tsconfig.json and webpack.config for reference

Comment: When set the minchunkcount to infinity webpack will not looking for any repeated libraries on your source and try to export it as separated file. for your reference you can see chunk section of the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#passing-the-minchunks-property-a-function

Comment: "23 to 25 minutes" - dood, what is going on?!

Comment: We don't have specific file that we want load dynamically, so we are using the complete folder structure in System.import and it's creating chunk files for all the components in our application, this is impacting build time.

Comment: @Nour: Now I have implemented to import 20 components as on-demand and that reduced the build time. Making minChunks:Infinity did not really improve build time and it may not be the reason for this issue.Thanks for help!